# Show/Hide (drop/down) area to show a menu

Tags: jquery, plugins, menu, joomla, drop-down-menu

1. I want to create a drop down area like once in the top of [templatemonster.com](http://www.templatemonster.com) .It shows when mouse over it and hide when mouse cursor get out of it. can you introduce me a jquery plugin for this?

   2. Also I'm going to add a menu like the top menu of templatemonster.com to this hidden area. How can I make this one? ( specialised with a horizontal sub-menues)

> meanwhile I'll use these feature in a
>   joomla! template. any special
>   suggestion for joomla! here? (plugin
>   and etc)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use superfish jquery plugin for menu (http://users.tpg.com.au/j%5Fbirch/plugins/superfish/#examples)

and

this jquery dropdown plufing for my hidden area (www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dropdownpanel.shtml)

Thank you again my friends

Answer (score 3):

check out superfish jquery plugin

Demo: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

Answer (score 1):

+1 on the superfish extension, although you pretty much have to know some css to use it.  There's not an extension that I know of that would won't need some css ability.

Another option would be to find a template that already has a dropdown menu system built in.  Find a template that you like, and make sure the demo has drop-down menus, and you'll be all set.  The templates will have their own individual directions on how to populate the menus, but it generally straightforward.  Usually you will create a menu, and some of the menu items will have other items as parents.

Comment: Thank you alot Dear SDGator :) / your response was useful for me